# Hibernate One-To-Many and Many-to-One mapping

Tags: hibernate

I know this topic has been discussed before here.But I still am facing issues.I have two tables - `Person` and `Accounts`.`PERSON_ID` is the primary key in the Person table and foreign key in the child table Accounts.
I have one screen on my web app which helps maintain the `Person table`.Now on the second `screen-Accounts`,I am facing an issue with the mapping.I believe I have the right annotations in the Parent and Child classes.But with the second screen when I try to insert a new `Account` the `person_id` is being inserted as "null" in the Accounts table after which an Update statement on the same Accounts table is fired.Not sure why these two issues are occurring.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code for Entity, Controller and JSP.

Comment: what is value you have specified for  'cascade' attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

I am explaining the scenario `Account * ----- 1 Person`

Hibernate mapping for **Person** Model will be like

```
<hibernate-mapping package="models">
<class name="Person" table="HIB_PER">
        <id name="perID" column="PER_ID">
            <generator class="native"></generator>  
        </id>
        <set name="accounts" lazy="true" cascade="all">
           <key column="PER_ID"  />
           <one-to-many class="Account"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate mapping for **Account** Model will be like

```
<hibernate-mapping package="models">
    <class name="Account" table="HIB_ACC">
        <id name="accID" column="ACC_ID">
            <generator class="native"></generator>  
        </id>
    <many-to-one name="person" class="Person" column="PER_ID" lazy="no-proxy"  fetch="select"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Both models(POJO) will look like

```
class Person {
    private int perID;
    private Set<Account> accounts;
    //getters and setters
}

class Account {
    private int accID;
    private Person person;
   //getters and setters
}
```

Now important part is that in the above structure
with the help of hibernate **you can save Person object alone** in database.
But in case of Account object you have **save Person object first then his all Accounts** in database.

Therefore,
accounding to your screen,

**Screen-1** accepts Person information and saves it in database like

```
Person p = new Person();
//set its setters
//save to DB
session.save(p)
```

**Screen-2** accepts one by one account information likned to above person and save it in database.But important point here is that your have to maintain **persons ID i.e perID** in hidden field so that you will actually know whose account is this.

```
Person p = get from Database with help of perID

Account acc1 =  new Account();
//set its setters
//set its owner
acc1.setPerson(p);

Account acc2 =  new Account();
//set its setters
//set its owner
acc2.setPerson(p);

//save to DB
session.save(acc1)
session.save(acc2)
```

Here without Person, Account object will not be saved in database. That means account is tightly coupled with person with help of hibernates one-to-many relation and **perID as foreign key will be automatically created by hibernate in account table**.

Comment: Thanks.I think I made a mistake with the wrong value being passed.It works now.Thanks all for your quick responses.